# How to replace the default font for the whole OS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, fonts

Is there a way to make my app override the current font of the currently foreground application?

What I have in mind is no matter which app is on foreground my app to be able to attach a button to the keyboard which will switch the font to a custom one thus overriding the current font for all ui elements(labels, buttons, text fields etc.).

Comment: Don't think it's possible...for non jailbroken phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is not allowed by Apple.

It seems it can be done for [jailbroken devices](http://colorkeyboard.9eye.net/faq) though. It's difficult to tell how exactly they're doing it but I guess they meddled around with the images/colors provided by Apple for the keyboard and replaced them with their custom ones leaving the default un-recoverable.

[Here's](http://tiffanytan0622.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-change-iphone-keyboard-to-p-i-n.html) a blog about it too.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be all I need. I also suspected Apple wouldn't allow this but I needed someone to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a category on UIFont and replace `systemFontWithName:size:` and `boldSystemFontWithName:size:` with your own font. But this may have some weird side effects, as even alertViews and actionSheets are customized with that method..

edit: of course this works only in your own app.. you cannot change anything outside of your app.